# Ansible Remove Duplicate IP Address from the inventory host file

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a host group as stated below like that,

**Inventory File:**

```
[test]
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.1
```

**Playbook:**

```
---
- hosts: test
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Something to print.."
```

If execute the playbook, it won't execute the task on the duplicate IP Address, Simply it will skip.
Because the 192.168.1.1 it will come here two times, so the duplicate entries should not be executed.
How do I make this happen using ansible.

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"Remove duplicate items from the inventory file."***

A: Use the utility *ansible-inventory* and fix the inventory. Given the inventory with duplicate entry

```
shell> cat hosts
[test]
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.1
```

Ansible ignores the duplicate hosts. For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: test
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml
...

ok: [192.168.1.1] => 
  inventory_hostname: 192.168.1.1
ok: [192.168.1.2] => 
  inventory_hostname: 192.168.1.2
ok: [192.168.1.3] => 
  inventory_hostname: 192.168.1.3
```

You can use the utility *ansible-inventory* and fix the inventory. For example, the command below will read the inventory *hosts* in INI format and will create *hosts.yaml* in YAML format

```
shell> ansible-inventory -i hosts --list --yaml > hosts.yaml
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat hosts.yaml 
all:
  children:
    test:
      hosts:
        192.168.1.1: {}
        192.168.1.2: {}
        192.168.1.3: {}
    ungrouped: {}
```

Now, you can use the YAML inventory. The play below will give the same results

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts.yaml pb.yml
```

Comment: Hi @Vladimir I have updated the inventory. So if you look at the inventory DB group and App Group contains the same IP.  I want to execute some tasks that should be run only one time.  Assume APP01 it's having 192.168.1.3 then it should perform the task.  How could I compare or exclude the duplicate IP address.

Comment: This is a different problem. There are no duplicates. Any host can be a member of more groups. Put the question back where it was and open a new question. Otherwise, I'll have to delete my answer because it does not answer the question anymore.

Comment: Yeah sure.. I'll create a separate question. Thanks